# Why universal covering space of $S^2$ is not $R^2$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I know the universal covering space of $S^2$ is $S^2$, where $S^2$ is 2-dimensional sphere. But as picture below, I feel $R^2$ also be the universal covering space of $S^2$. But, obviously, $S^2$ is not homeomorphism to $R^2$. Where is my mistake?

> [image]

Comment: You can actually make that construction with a piece of paper.  See what you get.

Comment: "Where is my mistake?": in the vagueness of "as picture below, I feel".

Comment: I believe the given diagram shows that $\mathbb R^2$ is the universal cover for the torus $\mathbb S^1\times\mathbb S^1$, not the sphere $\mathbb S^2$.

Comment: @BenjaminRoycraft This should be an official answer.

Comment: Have you tried to construct an explicit covering map? What are the evenly covered neighbourhoods? . The reason $S^{2}$ itself is a universal cover is because it is simply connected and the identity is a covering. Also in the picture you have drawn, what do the arrows mean? . If they mean identification, then the space you are considering is the torus and not a sphere.

Comment: @BenjaminRoycraft No, it doesn't. The illustrated quotient map is certainly a surjective map $[0,1]^2\to S^2$. There isn't a single torus in this picture.

Comment: The reason there is no torus in this picture is cause the picture is mistaken. It's hard to tell where exactly, cause no explanation of the picture is provided. In the middle, there certainly is the fundamental square of the torus, i.e. you get a torus if you identify the sides in the indicated ways. So it's natural to assume that's where the mistake is.

Comment: If you identify the edges by gluing black to black, red to red, then you do indeed get a sphere, with the glued parts becoming a path on the surface of $S^2$. This won't define a covering map, though: the points on that path won't have evenly covered neighborhoods.

Comment: To follow up on the comment of @JohnPalmieri, the function $[0,1] \times [0,1] \mapsto S^2$ that is illustrated in your post is far from defining a function $\mathbb R^2 \to S^2$. So one wonders: what is the function $\mathbb R^2 \to S^2$ that you are proposing as a universal covering map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a familiar (I hope) picture of the plane as a covering space of the torus:

[image: plane covering torus]

Each intersection point is glued to the same vertex on the torus, and each point on the torus has an evenly covered neighborhood, because each point in the torus has a similar preimage in this picture: a preimage just like the intersection points which form the preimage of a point $v$.

In contrast, the only way I can make sense of your picture is like this:

[image: plane mapping to sphere]

The preimages of the points corresponding to those in the interiors of the rectangles will be different from the preimages of the points $a$ and $c$, and those will be different from the preimage of the point $b$. As a result, this is not a covering map. (I'm thinking of $a$, $b$, and $c$ as points on the sphere, and I've labeled a few of the points in their preimages.)